# JS onclick function no longer working to change link color

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

In an HTML script I wrote, I set up a JS function so that when the user clicks the text, it links out to the website AND changes the color of the text. I ended up copying that script and making a new one with changes (including taking out the JS function). Now that I am trying to put the function back in, it's not working. Looking back at the original script, the function works there and the use of the function looks right in the new one compared to the original... so I'm a little stuck on why the text won't change color anymore.

**Here is the JS Function**:

```
<script>
    function openPortal() {       
      window.open("http://www.google.com");
      document.getElementById("winapp").style.color="BlueViolet ";
    }</script>
```

**Here it's called in HTML,** first as an image link which works (and obviously I don't expect the color of the image to change so that's not my problem), then secondly as the text link that isn't changing color when clicked:

```
        <!--App Portal Link [Image] -->
<div style="left:23%" id="winlogo">
<p class="pos_winsym" id="winapp" onclick="openPortal()">
<span style="cursor:pointer">
<img src="winlogo.jpg" width="90" height="80">
    </span></div></p>
<p class="pos_winmsg">For Windows Applications
<br>

        <!--App Portal Link [Text] -->
<span style="cursor:pointer">
<a id="winapp" onclick="openPortal()" style="font-size:90%">Click here
    </a></p></span>
```

Any ideas on why the color no longer changes would be really helpful! Thank you!

FYI - let me know if more code is needed, I gave only what I think to be relevant to the situation.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing lots of work for what browsers implement by default. Why not have your `#winapp` tag set your href, with a `target="_blank"` attribute so that it opens up a new window or tab, and set the color via css in the style for `a:visited`

Comment: I originally had the target="_blank", but didn't know about the a:visited feature, so thank you! I do still like the JS implementation a little better on a personal level of scripting style and preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Modify your `id` to be unique** a page cannot contain two same `id`'s

Or you may modify your function as follows :

```
function openPortal( elem ) {       
   window.open("http://www.google.com");
   elem.style.color="blueviolet ";
}
```

And your `onclick` values as`openPortal( this )`

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xqyfa64y/1/)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I prefer this method, because in the other one, I would have to embed the link manually into one of the lines where I use the winapp ID. I need the link for both places. So I think this option is a cleaner for this case :)

Answer (score 2):

You have two of the same id's:

```
<p class="pos_winsym" id="winapp" onclick="openPortal()">
```

And here:

```
<a id="winapp" onclick="openPortal()" style="font-size:90%">Click here
</a>
```

Remove the id in the `<p>`:

```
<p class="pos_winsym" onclick="openPortal()">
```

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L3b0rhd9/)**